# Is it possible to `map_dict` on a nested dictionary?

Tags: python-polars

I have a straightforward data structure storing billing data. I'm trying to map that a CSV read in by Polars. If I use `map_elements`, I have Polars apparently hallucinating and making up replacement suggestion that just doesn't work.

```py
import polars as pl
import datetime

billing_data = {
    datetime.date(2022, 3, 11): {'usage': 896, 'amount': 119.7}, 
    datetime.date(2022, 4, 12): {'usage': 775, 'amount': 229.49}, 
    datetime.date(2022, 5, 12): {'usage': 1046, 'amount': 135.8}, 
    datetime.date(2022, 6, 13): {'usage': 1280, 'amount': 162.6}
}

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "billing_cycle": [datetime.date(2022, 3, 11), datetime.date(2022, 3, 12), datetime.date(2022, 3, 13), datetime.date(2022, 3, 14)]
})

df.with_columns(pl.col("billing_cycle").map_elements(lambda x: billing_data[x]["usage"]).alias("billing_usage"))
```

This gives something that just doesn't work as suggested

```py
Expr.map_elements is significantly slower than the native expressions API.
Only use if you absolutely CANNOT implement your logic otherwise.
In this case, you can replace your `map_elements` with the following:
  - pl.col("billing_cycle").map_elements(lambda x: ...)
  + 'usage'.map_dict(pl.col("billing_cycle").map_dict(billing_data))
```

The string `'usage'` has no attribute `map_dict`. I even tried using `pl.lit("usage"), but then it tells me that` Expr`object has no attribute`keys`.

I'm at a loss, since I apparently can't force Polars to let me use my inefficient solution, but I can't get their suggestion to work.

Comment: Polars will run the inefficient solution, but the code actually raises: `PanicException: python function failed KeyError: datetime.date(2022, 3, 12)` and that is what stops the execution. (It's difficult to see amongst all the warnings output.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've run into quite a few different issues here.

`.map_dict()` is essentially syntax sugar for a [*left-join*](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/86978f1077ef7f472f86630a028ad0b3b1a15ace/py-polars/polars/expr/expr.py#L9392C2-L9392C2).

In the case of nested data, it is probably simpler to use DataFrames and perform the join directly.

```py
df_bill = pl.DataFrame(
    {"billing_cycle": k, **v} for k, v in billing_data.items()
)
```

```py
# shape: (4, 3)
# ┌───────────────┬───────┬────────┐
# │ billing_cycle ┆ usage ┆ amount │
# │ ---           ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
# │ date          ┆ i64   ┆ f64    │
# ╞═══════════════╪═══════╪════════╡
# │ 2022-03-11    ┆ 896   ┆ 119.7  │
# │ 2022-04-12    ┆ 775   ┆ 229.49 │
# │ 2022-05-12    ┆ 1046  ┆ 135.8  │
# │ 2022-06-13    ┆ 1280  ┆ 162.6  │
# └───────────────┴───────┴────────┘
```

```py
df.join(df_bill, on="billing_cycle", how="left")
```

```py
# shape: (4, 3)
# ┌───────────────┬───────┬────────┐
# │ billing_cycle ┆ usage ┆ amount │
# │ ---           ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
# │ date          ┆ i64   ┆ f64    │
# ╞═══════════════╪═══════╪════════╡
# │ 2022-03-11    ┆ 896   ┆ 119.7  │
# │ 2022-03-12    ┆ null  ┆ null   │
# │ 2022-03-13    ┆ null  ┆ null   │
# │ 2022-03-14    ┆ null  ┆ null   │
# └───────────────┴───────┴────────┘
```

#### Warnings

The `InefficientWarning` is just a warning and is not stopping execution.

There is actually a `PanicException` further down in the traceback:

```py
--- PyO3 is resuming a panic after fetching a PanicException from Python. ---
PanicException: python function failed KeyError: datetime.date(2022, 3, 12)
```

It seems to be a bug triggered by using `datetime` objects as keys inside `.map_elements`

#### Incorrect suggestions

```py
  + 'usage'.map_dict(pl.col("billing_cycle").map_dict(billing_data))
```

An incorrect suggestion [can also be reported as a bug.](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12384)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the *most* efficient way to solve this problem, but through experimentation, I discovered that Polars is storing the nested dict as a `Struct` if I just rely on a single `map_dict`.

So, this...

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col("billing_cycle").map_dict(billing_data).alias("billing_usage"))
```

Gave me a column that looked like `Struct([Field('usage', Int64), Field('amount', Float64)])`. This gave me the idea to start looking at `Struct` methods, and I came to this

```py
(df
    .with_columns(pl.col("billing_cycle").map_dict(billing_data).alias("billing_usage"))  
    .with_columns(pl.col("billing_usage").struct.field("usage").alias("billing_usage"))
)
```

Which is weird, but at least it works! For whatever reason, trying to one-line it didn't work, which is why I had to break it up into 2 lines.

For posterity, what I *did* try was

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col("billing_cycle").map_dict(billing_data).struct.field("usage").alias("billing_usage"))
```

But all I got for my trouble was `StructFieldNotFoundError: usage`. Not sure why.

Comment: The `StructFieldNotFoundError` is due to a lack of schema propagation by `.map_dict()` - it currently returns a type of `pl.Unknown` which is why the 2nd `.with_columns()` context is needed (at this stage, Polars can correctly infer the schema) It is being looked at: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/11332#issuecomment-1810085567

Comment: The `StructFieldNotFoundError` has been fixed in `0.20.0`